# Is there a way to add an additional PGPPublicKeyRing to an already encrypted file without completly re-encrypting the complete file

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'w working on allowing the encryption of files up to 25GB instead of our current max of 20MB. The normal encryption/decryption are no problem but we allow the addition of optional PGPPublicKeyRings after the file has already been encrypted.
Untill now we would just re-encrypt the file with all keys including the new optional keys. But with the increased filesize the current solution of re-encrypting every time would be very time consuming.

Is there anyway with bouncy castle to simply add an additional PGPPublicKeyRing given that you have all the data to decrypt the file?

Comment: If no answer is forthcoming use Bouncy Castle dev mailing list and post response here.